Why do I need sync.Pool?
I'm new to Go and I want to figure out why sync.Pool is needed. It's not entirely clear what the benefits of are sync.Pool compared to storing structures in ordinary variables, such as:
type myPool struct {
    v   any
    New func() any
}

func (p *myPool) Get() any {
    if p.v == nil {
        return p.New()
    }

    return p.v
}

func (p *myPool) Put(v any) {
    p.v = v
}


"It's not entirely clear what the benefits of are sync.Pool" - perhaps so far you might only have had exposure to smaller Go projects, such as command-line programs or things you run locally; but if I tell you think about considerably larger Go programs: like a web-service application which will exist as a running process in-memory serving possibly hundreds of thousands of requests every minute for days or weeks at a time before being recycled-out (and not even crashing once) then you might see there's a need for pooling then.

@Dai In large projects, there is most likely a real benefit. My question is more about what are the advantages of implementing sync.Pool from my myPool? The question may be silly, but it's interesting to understand

The documentation includes behaviors, purpose, and examples.

A pool is a collection, that can hold multiple instances, and is designed to gracefully handle common consumer error-type issues (e..g thread safety), and might have associated threads/timers/services that handle things like safely disposing of expensive pooled resources if it's no-longer necessary; whereas your code is basically a deferred-initialized (and never free'd) thread-unsafe single singleton. Basically it comes down to "why have everyone reinvent the wheel poorly, or have an actually good implementation everyone can use?"

An application can implement all of the sync.Pool functionality except for this feature:

If the Pool holds the only reference when this happens, the item might be deallocated.

The runtime and  sync.Pool work together to implement weak references. It's not possible to replicate this functionality in an application.
Separate from the weak reference feature, sync.Pool implements several features not present in the question's pool.  See the documentation for a description of the features.

sync.Pool creates a fixed number or a pool of things for use, commonly used to constraint things that are expensive (for example DB connections)
Get()
When the get method is called, it checks the pool to return a resource. If there is an available resource, the Get method will return that, if there is no available resource it will call New to create a new resource and return it. When the use of that resource is over then we must call Put()
Put()
We call the put method to place that used resource back into the pool for use when it needed
